# How to get BibTex reference of a matlab code

Tags: matlab, bibtex, citations

I want to cite a matlab documented code from  https://www.mathworks.com/. How can I get a BibTex reference of the code?

Comment: What referencing style are you using? Just follow those guidelines for any other code or website. Are you struggling with the BibTex formatting? You might want to look at [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

If it is code from MATLAB (not from the File Exchange) you can:

- Just cite MATLAB
- Get the bibliography of the theory from the "References" section of
  the documentation

If it is from the FEX, depends

- If the FEX is software that comes from a paper (normally the authors will try to tell you), then cite the paper
- Else, follow Mathworks guidelines: http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/12/13/citing-file-exchange-submissions/